# Access denied on admin/structure

Tags: 8, users

I have defined a new user role "Webmaster", and assigned it the permissions to administer forms, menu & menu items and taxonomy terms (all). Going to the admin/structure url still yields an "Access denied".

What permissions do I need set to allow my webmasters access to the admin/structure url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user needs the permission "Use the administration pages and help".

Then the user can access `/admin` and `/admin/structure`.

If the user has no other admin rights, the admin menus will be rather empty. They will fill up if you assign more permissions.